# Javascript regex that escapes \ sign

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to convert string that has following values

```
"A\"s\"sets"
```

my goal is to remove from string \ values no matter how many of them appear in string.

```
 "A"s"sets"
```

I tried using new RegExp but I do not manage to perform that operation.
I even managed to create regex that will pick up everything except \ sign

```
[a-zA-Z0-9'"*]
```

I also tried calling on

```
regex.exec(string)
```

but I am getting an array instead of cleared string.
Anyone have any idea how to do this ?
Thank you

Comment: Those slashes \ that you see aren't actually slashes, they escape the special meaning characters like `"` needs to be escaped in a string.

Comment: It does not provide proper result unless your string has \ one next to another, here is a fiddle of an example with randomly inputed \ in string http://jsfiddle.net/hwe869ro/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace.

```js
let str = `"A\"s\\"sets"`

let op = str.replace(/\\+/g, '')

console.log(op)
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It only appears to work because you constructed the value of `str` incorrectly so the slashes are treated as escape sequences and are not part of the data. Your regular expression removes `+` characters! Since there aren't any, `op === str`

Comment: @Quentin updated now it will

Comment: @CodeManiac: If you really want to have slash in your string, you need to escape it and write double slashes in the string. Try running this `console.log(str)` You will see there are no slashes printed in the string.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi i think you didn't noticed the updated one ? did you ?

Comment: That one works great even if I get mangled string that escaped 10 double quotes like "A\"s\"\"\"\"\"s\"e\"ts" it will extract all slashes, thank you so much CM !
The problem is that I am getting string from velocity and this is what I am getting and what I need to intercept in order to avoid any value issues when it reaches JS, otherwise it would not be the problem. Thank you again CM !